# Node JS как принимать POST запрос?

Tags: node.js

Я знаю что есть метод apt.post. Но я не хочу его использовать так как там придеться указывать каждую ссылку. Я хочу чтобы сайт открывался по всем путям например site.com/path-1, site.com/path-2

И я решил использовать это, сайт открывается по всем ссылкам но он не видит данные отправленные формой. Хотя если оптравить через postman то все он видит что можно сделать ?

```
app.use((req, res) => {
   console.log(req._parsedUrl)
});
```

Comment: Постмен отправляет post запросы? Смотрите отдельно заголовки.

Comment: @SwaD да он отправляет пост запросы, в заголовках тоже ничего. вот пример ```const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const http = require('http');
const server = http.createServer(app);

app.use((req, res) => {
 console.log(req._parsedUrl.query);
 res.send(`<form action="" method="post">
        <input type="text" name="name">
        <button>Submit</button>
    </form>`);
});


server.listen(80, () => {
  console.log('listening on *:80');
});```

Comment: Вот некая документация по работе с формами... https://metanit.com/web/nodejs/4.5.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как я понял, вы используете express. Для того что бы получить body, необходимо использовать [bodyParser](https://www.npmjs.com/package/body-parser).
В начало программы добавьте `app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }))`.

**P.S.**
Все пути можно использовать и с app.post

```
app.post((res, req) => {
 console.log(req.body);
}
```

Comment: а почему пакет bodyParser, а не встроенный функционал express?

Comment: @nörbörnën потому что express не имеет такого функционала и в своей документации  
рекомендует использовать body-parser http://expressjs.com/en/5x/api.html#req.body

Comment: https://expressjs.com/en/5x/api.html#req.body:~:text=express.urlencoded(%5Boptions%5D)

Comment: Это обёртка для того же самого body-parser, поэтому разницы нет никакой.